# Trying to fill text box with only class name

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, browser, getelementsbytagname

```
<input class="input" maxlength="200">
```

This is the code in HTML and it makes a text box. I'm trying to enter things into that text box (with webBrowser), and I can get that element by the tag name, I just don't know how to enter text, because it has no attribute like "value" or "text" or anything... That's all there is. It's not my server either, so I can't change anything.

Full code:

```
<div><label>Enter input: <input class="input"
maxlength="200"></label></div>
```

Deleting the

```
<input class="input" maxlength="200">
```

deletes the text box from the page...
How can I enter text into that box?

My code:

```
foreach(HtmlElement z in webBrowser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input")){
     try{
     z.SetAttribute("value", "My text"); //Can't set attribute because it has none
     } catch(Exception zz){};
}
```

Comment: You should post the C# code you have written to try and accomplish this.  The HTML code is only half of the information needed.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have the `HtmlElement`:

```
htmlElement.SetAttribute("value", "My textbox value");
```

**EDIT:** Full code:

```
foreach(HtmlElement z in webBrowser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input")) {
    if (z.GetAttribute("className") == "input") {
        z.SetAttribute("value", "My text");
    }
}
```

Refer to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmlelement.setattribute.aspx) about the SetAttribute function:

> If attributeName is not a defined attribute on an element, SetAttribute will define it on the element as a new attribute.

Comment: What I posted WAS the html element. There is no "value" attribute to the textbox, it does nothing. The class name is the only thing defining the textbox.

Comment: The code actually works for me. If the attribute `value` doesn't exist it gets created. The code you added in your question doesn't compile as it's missing a `)`. Did you try it? I've updated my answer with code that works for the HTML-element `<input class="input" maxlength="200">`.

Comment: Oh yeah, edited that.. Thanks. And the attribute "value" does get added, but the page doesn't use it as input in the textbox, and the server doesn't read anything from the "value" either. When I click the submit button for the text box, it sends a link with something like `www.page.com/input=theinputhere`

Comment: Is your code simplified or does the input not have a name attribute? I think it has to have a name attribute, otherwise the data isn't posted with the form.

Comment: Nope, `<input class="input" maxlength="200">` is literally the only code for the textbox. Removing that code and that code only removes the whole textbox, and no data can be sent. After the button is clicked, a request is sent to for example `www.page.com/input=theinputhere` with `POST_DATA = ""` and `Content-Length = 0` ... If there's a way to intercept the request / `www.page.com/input=theinputhere` from webBrowser and replace `theinputhere` with anything else, that would be fine too. It's just that it doesn't redirect to `/input=theinputhere`, it sends a request.

Comment: How does the form tag look?

Comment: `<form style="margin-top: 0.5em; margin-bottom: 0.5em;">
<div><label><strong>Enter input:</strong><br>
<input class="input" maxlength="200">
</label></div></form>`

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using  `element.SetAttribute("value", "My text")` use `element.InnerText="My text"`

**See my example**

```
public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted;
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            webBrowser1.DocumentText = "<div><label>Enter input: <input class=\"input\"maxlength=\"200\"></label></div>";
        }

        void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (HtmlElement element in webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input"))
            {
               if(element.GetAttribute("className")=="input")
               {
                   element.InnerText="My text";
                }
            }
        }
```